# How to address the surrounding naming container in jsf?

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a jsf 2.0 page with a `<p:dataTable>` and inside this table a `<p:commandButton>` that should delete an item from this table with an ajax request. The deleting itself works fine, but I do not know how to identify the surrounding `<p:dataTable>` for the render `update`.

```
<lots of naming containers>
...
   <p:dataTable id="dataTable" var="userItem" ... />
     <p:column>

        <p:commandButton
             action="#{userController.doDelete(userItem.id)}"
             value="delete" 
             update="?????"/>  <!-- How to address the dateTable? -->

     </p:column>
   </p:dataTable>
<.lots of naming containers>
```

<del>I already tryed `update="dataTable"` but mojarra did not find it</del>
(*Edit: it did not worked for an other reason*)

So my question is how to address the surrounding naming container, WITHOUT using a absolute path that starts at root `UIComponent` (because then I would need to name a lot of naming containers.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you have everything within a form that has `prependId="false"` as an attribute, then the update attribute value of `dataTable` should work.

The PrimeFaces update attribute of child components recognizes the id of a parent dataTable component.  Furthermore you can also use the `@parent` value within PrimeFaces update to re render a child elements immediate parent container.

Comment: You are right there was something wrong with the dataTable. -- I have overlooked an naming container in the column (I simplyfied the posted code) -- Thanks for yor answer, because it made me review the code again.

Comment: I got stuck again with the related problem, maybe you can help me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12090950/how-to-access-the-parent-naming-container-of-composite