# How to access the parent Naming Container of Composite?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, composite-component, clientid

I have a JSP 2.0 `<ui:component>`, within that is a `<p:dataTable>` with a column that uses a Composite to render a special border about some content. Now I need to identify the `<p:dataTabe>` in a ajax rendered attribute that is located in the content.

```
<ui:component>
  <p:dataTable id="dataTable" var="userItem" ... />
    <p:column>

        <my:borderBox id="borderBox">
           <p:commandButton
               action="#{userController.doDelete(userItem.id)}"
               value="delete" 
               update="?????"/>  <!-- How to address the dateTable? -->
        </my:borderBox>

      </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
 <ui:component>
```

My BorderBox:

```
<html xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite" ...>
   <composite:interface>
      <composite:attribute name="styleClass" default="" type="java.lang.String"/>
   </composite:interface>

   <composite:implementation>
      <h:panelGroup ...>
         ...
         <composite:insertChildren/>
      </h:panelGroup>
   </composite:implementation>
```

My idea was to use something like

`update=":#{component.namingContainer.parent.namingContainer.clientId}:dateTable`

But `component.namingContainer.parent` seams to be null.

When I replace the `<p:commandButton>` with this statements:

```
Parent ClientId 1: #{component}
Parent ClientId 2: #{component.namingContainer}
Parent ClientId 3: #{component.namingContainer.clientId}

Parent ClientId 4: #{component.namingContainer.parent}
Parent ClientId 5: #{component.namingContainer.parent.namingContainer}
```

I get this output:

```
Parent ClientId 1: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlPanelGroup@3d957419

Parent ClientId 2: javax.faces.component.UINamingContainer@23db9e8f
Parent ClientId 3: main_form:profilTabView:dataTable:0:borderBox

Parent ClientId 4:
Parent ClientId 5:
```

I have no idea what the problem it: mybey my idea to identify the list is complete wrong or there some mistake or there is a better way? (But I can not use fix absolute identifyer for the dateTable!)

*Versions: Primeface 3.2, Mojarra 2.1.6 on Glassfish 3.1.2*

Comment: I unfortunately don't use `ui:component` tag so I don't know much about it; I typically use Composite Components which you can reference from an EL expression the parent naming container like `#{cc.parent.id}`.  I think however that `parent` is a reserved variable in EL expression language so it should be as simple as `#{parent.id}` to retreive the parent naming container id.

Comment: @maple_shaft: `<ui:component>` is implicitly used by composite components. It is therefore cleaner to declare it directly instead of `<ui:composition>`.

Comment: Which JSF impl/version and PF version exactly are you using?

Comment: @BalusC: I use an unmodified Glassfish 3.1.2 (I can update to 3.1.2.2 if it is a bug) so it is Mojarra 2.1.6;  Primeface is version 3.2.

Comment: did you resolve this problem ?

Comment: @JamesN: no - I quitted

Answer (score 1):

I have a workaround for this Problem. If you can not find another solution, you can use it as an alternative. The Solution is a mix between jsf and javascript. For your table you define a widget (e.g. "myTable").

```
<p:dataTable id="dataTable" var="userItem" ...  widgetVar="myTable"/>
```

It is a global javascript variable named "myTable" is created. this widget object contains an id. For you command button (h:commandButton not p:commandButton) you define onklick event:

```
<h:commandButton id="deleteItem" action="#{userController.doDelete(userItem.id)}"
 value="delete" onclick="PrimeFaces.ab({formId:$(this).closest('form').attr('id'),source:this.id,process:'@all',update:myTable.id});return false;" />
```

formId - you enter the form ID explicitly or use my Jquery function 
update - myTable.id is a Table ID (exactly div wrapper)
process - @all, @this, @form etc..