# How to access a composite component's sibling via clientId

Tags: jsf, composite-component, clientid, naming-containers

I have a composite component that bundles some input fields. The component will be used multiple times on a page and contains a button to copy the values of another of these components. For this I would need to access one of those siblings via its clientId as a target for an

`<f:ajax execute=":XXX:siblingId" render="...">`

My problem lies in constructing this ID. I have the name of the sibling and I can make sure that it is located in the same naming container as the component that contains the copy button, but I can't control the complete nesting hierarchy, so it might be `:form:foo:bar:parent:child` or just `form:parent:child`. So essentially I would want to get the prefix of the current composite component, but *without* the component's own ID and then attach the ID of the component from which to copy.

This is similar to these questions:

- [How to address the surrounding naming container in jsf](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12088654/840977)
- [How to access the parent naming container of composite](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12090950/840977)

However, both answers make use of PrimeFaces-sepcific features like `@parent` and `widgetVar`, which does not apply to my project.

When experimenting with EL's implicit objects I basically tried the same things as the poster of the second question - with the same results: `cc.parent.clientId` is always empty. I also tried `cc.namingContainer.clientId` and some combinations of the two, alas - no success. Especially the fact that `parent` does not work as expected confuses me...

So: Is there a component-library-agnostic way to access the "path" of containing naming containers for a composite component? How is the `parent` object supposed to work, especially: when can we use it and when not?

PS: I was thinking about using the composite's full clientId and then trimming its actual ID with `fn:split`, however, if there was a more direct way I'd be happy to use it.

Comment: By the way, the `<f:ajax>` doesn't support the `process` attribute, it's instead the `execute` attribute. The `process` attribute is specific to PrimeFaces components :)

Comment: Right, of course. I always mix these up. As a non-native speaker that word always reminds me of guillotines rather than doing stuff - hence the preference for 'process' ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `#{cc.parent}` resolves to [`UIComponent#getCompositeComponentParent()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getCompositeComponentParent%28javax.faces.component.UIComponent%29) which returns the closest parent composite component. In other words, it returns only non-`null` when the composite component is by itself nested in another composite component.

The `#{cc.namingContainer}` simply refers to `#{cc}` itself, fully conform as specified in [`UIComponent#getNamingContainer()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getNamingContainer%28%29):

> **Starting with "this"**, return the closest component in the ancestry that is a `NamingContainer` or `null` if none can be found.

Composite components namely implicitly implement `NamingContainer` themselves.

So your attempts unfortunately won't work. I also do not see any "standard API" ways to achieve the concrete functional requirement. The `CompositeComponentAttributesELResolver` causes that the `#{cc.parent}` doesn't resolve to [`UIComponent#getParent()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getParent%28%29) which is what you ultimately want.

You can however provide a custom `UIComponent` implementation for the composite which adds an extra getter with an unique name which in turn properly delegates to `UIComponent#getParent()`.

Here's a kickoff example:

```
@FacesComponent("myComposite")
public class MyComposite extends UINamingContainer {

    public UIComponent getParentComponent() {
        return super.getParent();
    }

}
```

If you register it as follows in the composite interface:

```html
<cc:interface componentType="myComposite">
```

then you'll be able to use

```
#{cc.parentComponent.clientId}
```

to get the client ID of the *real* parent `UIComponent`.

Ultimately you should be able to use the following construct to refer the sibling:

```
process=":#{cc.parentComponent.clientId}:siblingId"
```